# Transpacific travel with dog

Tags: international-travel, pets, pacific-ocean

We are living in West Coast USA and are moving to Asia. Our dog has a severe emotional issue because he was a rescue from the streets. He is unable to be kenneled without massive panic attacks, anxiety, mania. So, he cannot fly. We are looking for options to bring him to Asia on ship or small charter plane where he could be with us in the cabin. Any thoughts? Thank you so much!

Comment: Google searches (`X travel with dog` where X is one of `freighter`, `ocean`, `transpacific`, etc.) turned up some businesses that cater to this; have you considered them already?

Comment: Also what sized dog are you talking about?  Chihuahua, Terrier, Rottweiler or Great Dane?

Comment: Are tranquilizers not an option?

Comment: You have a huge problem on your hand: private jets are prohibitively expensive (six figures in US dollars), freighters do not allow pets on board and as per this [site](http://pet-express.com/plan/commonly-asked-questions/) "The American Veterinary Medical Association and International Pet & Animal Transport Association (IPATA) strongly recommend against tranquilizing your pet". They recommend "Should your pet have an extremely anxious temperament, please speak with your Pet Relocation Specialist to discuss options which may include mild sedatives administered under veterinary supervision."

Answer (score 5):

As per [this post](http://www.schubachaviation.com/blog/3836/how-much-does-it-cost-to-charter-a-jet-to-hawaii/) chartering a plane as an example from San Diego to Hawaii starts from $65000. That's about half way across but chartering a large enough plane to cross without refueling in Hawaii is going to be even more expensive. In conclusion, I have severe doubts private jet is doable below $100000.

A [freighter trip](https://www.freightercruises.com/seaworthy_news_1504.php) will be roughly 2500-3500 EUR per person. Cheaper by far but takes a month. Edit: as @phoog mentions, pets are not allowed! [source](http://www.freightercruises.com/q_a_freighter_cruise_guide.php#anchor21) so this might not be an option for you.

OP asked whether there is a way to charter from Alaska into Siberia. The answer is yes, [Bering Air](http://www.beringair.com/russian-travel/) flies from Nome to Ugolny (Anadyr). This is a short flight, even for a small aircraft this will take less than an hour. From there, I would probably fly into Sokol (922 miles) and next day to Ignatyevo (Blagoveshchensk) (1122 miles). The latter distance will determine which plane can you charter unless you want to refuel which will make a daunting long, long journey even worse. Some small piston planes can even do the Ugolny-Ignatyevo flight in one go (2041 miles) -- expect that to take like seven hours.

Ignatyevo airport serves the "metropolis" called Blagoveshchensk which has a ferry into Heihe, China. You can then take the train to Harbin, then another to Beijing and then the Z5 direct train to Hanoi (this alone is 36 hours). Phew!

Comment: The passenger/freighter services I found online said that pets are not allowed, so it seems unlikely to be an option.

Comment: @phoog thanks. You are right, I found the source and added into the answer.

Comment: Yes, I have done the research. Here is one option but I am really lost with trying to navigate. Alaska and Russia are close. But the Bering Sea is one of the most dangerous crossings in the world. Russia was not allowing any entry into that area due to some autonomous zone issues but has just recently loosened restrictions.If I could find a boat or small plane from there to cross we can enter Russia>China>Vietnam. Perfect. How can i find some options for that scenario??

Comment: @DirkBeszia amended my answer but you probably need to ask a separate question about where to hire a puddle jumper plane from Ugolny into Ignatyevo.